# How to auto-launch a jar file?

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar, execute

I have a game on a USB drive called `MyGame.jar`.

It is an executable jar file. I want to be able to put it on cd's and USB drives.

I want the game to start up automatically when the `cd` or `USB` is put into the computer, how can i do this?

The game will only be ran on Windows based computers(Windows Xp & Windows 7).

Comment: Have you tried autoplay?

Comment: no, can you explain how to use it in an answer and ill try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to automatically launch an application using autoplay:

Make a text file and save it as `autorun.inf`. Save it in the base path of the CD.

The contents of `autorun.inf` should look something like this:

```
RUN=setup.exe
Icon=icon.ico
```

The `icon` field is optional.

Note that this only works if the user has autoplay enabled. If the user disabled it, it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Creating an `autorun.inf` ([Autorun.inf entries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144200%28VS.85%29.aspx)) will work quite nicely for a CD.

But for USB drives, as of Windows 7, it can't be done. Microsoft disabled this "feature" because of all the malware that auto-installed that way...

In your case, the contents of `autorun.inf` should be something like this:

```
[autorun]
shellexecute=MyGame.jar
icon=MyIcon.ico
label=MyGameName
```

`shellexecute` opens `MyGame.jar` automatically using the jre (if installed). The other lines are optional but good practice.